# Python __del__ method output in "Interactive Mode" vs "Script Mode"

Tags: python, oop

I am new to Python and I came across the Python **del** method the other day and I have some doubts on the output of the following code.

So, the snippet code goes something like this:

```
class Robot():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name + " has been created!")

    def __del__(self):
        print ("Robot has been destroyed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Robot("Tik-Tok")
    y = Robot("Jenkins")
    z = x
    z
    x
    del x
    del z
    del y
```

Case 1: If I were to run the code in  “Script Mode”, the following output will be obtained:

Tik-Tok has been created!
Jenkins has been created!
Robot has been destroyed
Robot has been destroyed

Case 2: If I were to run the code in “Interactive Mode”, the following output will be obtained:

```
>>> x = Robot("Tik-Tok")
Tik-Tok has been created!
>>> y = Robot("Jenkins")
Jenkins has been created!
>>> z = x
>>> z
<__main__.Robot object at 0x02D7E910>
>>> x
<__main__.Robot object at 0x02D7E910>
>>> del x
>>> del z
>>> del y
Robot has been destroyed
```

My question being why is that “Robot has been destroyed” is only printed out only once in Case 2 (interactive mode) while it is printed out twice in Case 1 (script mode)?
I did some study on garbage collection and based on my understanding, after the `del x` and `del z` statements, the refcount to the Robot object should reach zero and subsequently triggers the `__del__` method as well right ? (just before the 2nd `__del__` method is triggered for the `del y` statement)

Comment: Do.Not.Implement. `__del__`. It almost *certainly* isn't useful, and could very well lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Also, what is up with your indentation?

Answer (score 2):

In the interactive interpreter, the result of the last expression evaluated is saved as `_`. This reference keeps Tik-Tok alive until another statement is typed in the interpreter.